# Set TimeOut Expired in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a stored procedure in sql server 2008 R2 which was working fine, but suddenly it throws an exception of TimeOut Expiration.

```
BmDaoSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec SP_Name @Param1  = '" + clientCode + "', @Param2 ='" + existingDatabase + "', @Flag='" + flag + "'").ExecuteUpdate();
```

I am using the above NHibernate command to call my SP.

My question is how Can I set the TimeOut Expiration in NHibernate. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add fluently `SetTimeout` method:

```
BmDaoSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec SP_Name @Param1  = '" + clientCode + "', @Param2 ='" + existingDatabase + "', @Flag='" + flag + "'")
    .SetTimeout(120)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

For more information you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955/nhibernate-settimeout-on-icriteria).

Comment: Please note the error. .SetTimeOut should be .SetTimeout in the code.